# Maven for game development / asset pipelines

Tags: maven, dependency-management, asset-management

I'm just exploring Maven as a build / dependency management tool and it seemed like it would be ideal for managing the (often quite complex!) dependencies in a typical game development scenario.

Some example scenarios:

- Converting 3D assets between formats / applying pre-processing steps to textures
- Rebuilding static in-game data structures such as pathfinding nodes when world maps change
- Handling the quite complex dependencies for platform-specific graphics libraries etc.

Has anyone had any success with this sort of approach?

Answer (score 1):

What are you planning on programming the game in?  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) on it suggests support for C++ is limited.  Have you considered [BuildBot](http://trac.buildbot.net/)?  It's 'Success Stories' page mentions a few games, among other things.

> Theoretically, this would allow anyone
>   to write plugins to interface with
>   build tools (compilers, unit test
>   tools, etc.) for any other language.
>   In reality, support and use for
>   languages other than Java has been
>   minimal. Currently a plugin for the
>   .Net framework exists and is
>   maintained [3], and a C/C++ native
>   plugin was at one time maintained for
>   Maven 1.[4]

Comment: I'm of the view that a full game dev pipeline would ultimately need to include tools written in all sorts of languages - so it clearly needs to support plugins for these. The reason for looking at Maven is that it is (as far as I'm aware) the closest to offering this.

Comment: p.s. BuildBot looks interesting but seems mostly focused on building, whereas Maven is positioned as a much more comprehensive projects/dependency management solution that happens to also do builds and packaging etc.

Comment: Hmm... truthfully it seems like a lot of what you want accomplished is best done through scripting and event hooks in source control, as you are also planning on wrangling content between updates.